# How to make changes in phoneGap ( Apache Cordova ) Api

Tags: android, cordova

I wanted to access my existing .db file from sdcard using phoneGap but method available in phoneGap accepts only database name not path as given below. 
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 600000);

so I thought to make changes in cordova-1.7.0.jar which has native code to communicate with device. I found Storage.java which has openDatabase(String db, String version, String display_name,long size) method wherein I just need to assign a variable i.e 
path = "/mnt/sdcard/database" and recompile the .jar file. so I downloaded cordova source from below given path i.e. https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android and made changes in this and created new .jar file to use in my project. but its giving error when application loads.

Comment: Did you end up writing this plugin successfully? Is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to write your code as a plugin as PhoneGap uses the WebKit database. There is already a plugin for accessing external SQLite database, but it is for iOS. Nevertheless, it would be a good starting point for you to write your own plugin for Android.  The existing plugin can be found in https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin

Comment: can`t I make changes in Storage.java of Cordova.jar and use it in my project.

Comment: You can, but there are several advantages if you make it a plugin. Without knowing what errors you are getting, it is difficult to help you more than giving suggestions.

Comment: I have downlaoded cordova source from given link i.e. https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android and at this page they have not given proper instruction for building jar file.

Comment: There are instructions for [building](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android#building). Please read through the documentation and if required, perform a search on the web and also on SO.

Comment: I have imported "framework" directory in my eclipse that was inside the .zip which I downlaoded from [apache cordova website](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android) but there is error in build.xml