# How can I work with a SQLite database in a PhoneGap application?

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I am developing an application for Android using PhoneGap.

I have to use an existing SQLite database (mydatabase.sqlite). How should I go about opening the database and performing operations on it?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201179/how-to-make-changes-in-phonegap-apache-cordova-api)  answers your question. Basically you need a cordova(phonegap) plugin to be able to use any SQLite db, otherwise it uses the one that webkit implementation creates.